# How do I insert input in a List<string>, without just adding the last input to List?

Tags: c#, foreach

So I'm making a "type in the correct word to the mixed up word" game to practice some c# as I'm pretty new to it. I've got a List< List < string >> that adds three lists: mixedwordslist, correctwortslist and the inputlist that I've just called "TheList". When I loop through the correctvalue to check if the user input is correct, I set the score to += 1. After that I want to add the input to the inputlist, thus not getting just the newest input.

I've tried to change every List to a Dictionary, so that I could just insert the index, and add it everytime it looped through an item. That worked, but when I wanted to output every value, it got too complicated and so I just went back to leaving my lists as List and not Dictionary.

Here's my code:

```cs
foreach (string mixedvalue in mixedword.mixedwordslist)
            {
                Console.Write($"\n{mixedvalue}:\t");
                input = Console.ReadLine();

                foreach (string correctvalue in correctword.correctwordslist)
                {
                    if (input.Equals(correctvalue))
                    {
                        score += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                }

                inputlist.inputlist.Add(input);

            }
```

Comment: I don't understand what it's not doing for you. You want to add it to a list... which you do at the end of the function. Please clarify, what do you want it to do? What is it actually doing instead? You must mean something more complex than just "insert into list" based on the wording of your question. What do you mean by "I want to add the input to the inputlist, thus not getting just the newest input"?

Comment: @IanKirkpatrick For example: mixedword = "doof", my input would be: "food". Then the next mixedword would show, like: "thera", my input would be: heart. What it does, is, it just adds the last input to the list, so in this case it would just add "heart", and not "food". Thanks for your patience though.

Comment: How is this not working? That's exactly what it looks like this does

Comment: @IanKirkpatrick Well it didn't... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect situation for LINQ.

So that you're not modifying a list while you're cycling through it, you'll so a select on the list. Assuming your lists are just List you should be able to replace your inner foreach loop. It looks like you might have some unnecessary nested properties but you could do something like this instead.

First check if score needs update.

```
if(correctwordslist.Where(x=>x == input).Any())
{
    score += 1;
}
```

Then add to the input list if it hasn't already been tried.

```
if(!inputlist.Where(x=>x==input).Any())
    inputlist.Add(input);
```